Cannot assign a many-to-many relationship in spring-jpa
There is a problem with Spring's many-to-many relationship behavior. I have 2 entities, Video.java and Tag.java. Video:
@Entity
@Table(name = "video")
public class Video {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "url")
    private String url;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name = "is_family_friendly")
    private Boolean isFamilyFriendly;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @URL
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "image_url")
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "duration")
    private Integer duration;

    @Past
    @Column(name = "publish_date")
    private LocalDate publishDate;

    @Column(name = "genre")
    private VideoGenreEnum genre;

    @URL
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "author_link")
    private String authorUrl;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "author")
    private String author;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="transcription")
    private String transcription;

    @Column(name = "language")
    private VideoLanguageEnum language;

    @Column(name = "difficulty_level")
    private DifficultyLevelEnum difficultyLevel;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "video_tag",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "video_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFamilyFriendly() {
        return isFamilyFriendly;
    }

    public void setIsFamilyFriendly(Boolean isFamilyFriendly) {
        this.isFamilyFriendly = isFamilyFriendly;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Integer getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public LocalDate getPublishDate() {
        return publishDate;
    }

    public void setPublishDate(LocalDate publishDate) {
        this.publishDate = publishDate;
    }

    public VideoGenreEnum getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(VideoGenreEnum genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getAuthorUrl() {
        return authorUrl;
    }

    public void setAuthorUrl(String authorUrl) {
        this.authorUrl = authorUrl;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTranscription() {
        return transcription;
    }

    public void setTranscription(String transcription) {
        this.transcription = transcription;
    }

    public VideoLanguageEnum getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(VideoLanguageEnum language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public DifficultyLevelEnum getDifficultyLevel() {
        return difficultyLevel;
    }

    public void setDifficultyLevel(DifficultyLevelEnum difficultyLevel) {
        this.difficultyLevel = difficultyLevel;
    }

    public Set<Tag> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<Tag> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}

Tag:
@Entity
@Table(name = "tag")
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, updatable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(name = "content", unique = true)
    private String content;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Video> videos;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Set<Video> getVideos() {
        return videos;
    }

    public void setVideos(Set<Video> videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
    }
}

Their corresponding DTO objects are VideoData.java:
public class VideoData {

    private String id;
    private String url;
    private String title;
    private Boolean isFamilyFriendly;
    private String description;
    private String imageUrl;
    private Integer duration;
    private LocalDate publishDate;
    private VideoGenreEnum genre;
    private String authorUrl;
    private String author;
    private String transcription;
    private VideoLanguageEnum language;
    private DifficultyLevelEnum difficultyLevel;
    private Set<UUID> tags;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public Boolean getIsFamilyFriendly() {
        return isFamilyFriendly;
    }

    public void setIsFamilyFriendly(Boolean isFamilyFriendly) {
        this.isFamilyFriendly = isFamilyFriendly;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Integer getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Integer duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public LocalDate getPublishDate() {
        return publishDate;
    }

    public void setPublishDate(LocalDate publishDate) {
        this.publishDate = publishDate;
    }

    public VideoGenreEnum getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(VideoGenreEnum genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getAuthorUrl() {
        return authorUrl;
    }

    public void setAuthorUrl(String authorUrl) {
        this.authorUrl = authorUrl;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }

    public String getTranscription() {
        return transcription;
    }

    public void setTranscription(String transcription) {
        this.transcription = transcription;
    }

    public VideoLanguageEnum getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(VideoLanguageEnum language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public DifficultyLevelEnum getDifficultyLevel() {
        return difficultyLevel;
    }

    public void setDifficultyLevel(DifficultyLevelEnum difficultyLevel) {
        this.difficultyLevel = difficultyLevel;
    }

    public Set<UUID> getTags() {
        return tags;
    }

    public void setTags(Set<UUID> tags) {
        this.tags = tags;
    }
}

TagData.java:
public class TagData {

    private UUID id;
    private String content;
    private Set<UUID> videos;

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public Set<UUID> getVideos() {
        return videos;
    }

    public void setVideos(Set<UUID> videos) {
        this.videos = videos;
    }
}

The body for post request looks like this:
{
    "url": "https://www.example.com/your-video.mp4",
    "title": "My Awesome Video Title",
    "isFamilyFriendly": true,
    "description": "This is a great video about...",
    "imageUrl": "https://www.example.com/video_thumbnail.jpg",
    "duration": 100,
    "publishDate": "2023-03-29",
    "genre": "EDUCATIONAL",
    "authorUrl": "https://www.example.com/author-profile",
    "author": "John Doe",
    "transcription": "This is the video transcript...",
    "language": "ENGLISH",
    "difficultyLevel": "A1",
    "tags": [
        "bcdbb72b-aaa2-4818-9db7-da0447a210c8"
    ]
}

However, when I send a post request, this exception pops up:
Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of `com.arsenydeveloper.applangspringvideo.domain.tag.Tag` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('bcdbb72b-aaa2-4818-9db7-da0447a210c8')]

What am I doing wrong?

Well, look at the data you send for the tags and the constructors in Tag. Which of the 2 would you choose? While Spring can call setters as well the fact that there is a constructor that takes arguments makes it think that's your preferred way ... which it can't use due to lack of arguments. - And btw: would "bcdbb72b-aaa2-4818-9db7-da0447a210c8" be the tag's uuid or content? (Think from the system's perspective which just gets a string).

@Thomas Of course "bcdbb72b-aaa2-4818-9db7-da0447a210c8" is an ID and I guess Spring knows that, because I set tags field in VideoData to the type of Set<UUID>, so, as far as I know, it accepts a list of tags' IDs

Removed constructors from the JPA entities, the error stays the same

It looks as if Spring tries to deserialize the request directly into Video and thus wants to create Tag instances instead of using VideoData and TagData first. I'm not that familiar with how Spring relates entities to DTOs - did you set that up or is there any automatic conversion?

@Thomas Yes, I have set up automatic conversion from  Video to VideoData and Tag to TagData. The solution was to change private Set<UUID> tags to private Set<TagData> tags in VideoData and private Set<UUID> videos to private Set<VideoData> videos in TagData. Now, it is possible to pass tags as objects in the request: "tags": [{"id": "335ae591-5b22-4d14-a0e1-b63e46c5164d"}]. I came from django-rest, that's why I used to putting just only IDs in relation fields. Thank you for your help anyway!
